# How do I create another MailChimp account associated with my email address?

Tags: mailchimp

When I log in into MailChimp, I can see two accounts associated with my email address:

[image]

How do I add a third?

Comment: What does "create a new one" do?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise it let's me join in with a new email instead of creating another account associated with this email address.

Answer (score 1):

Advice [here](https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/login/manage-multiple-accounts-with-one-login) (with images) includes:

To send an account invitation to the email associated with your primary account   login, follow these steps.

```
Log in to your secondary MailChimp account.
Click your profile name and choose Account.
Profile menu with cursor on Account.
Click the Settings drop-down menu and choose Users.
Settings drop-down menu with cursor on User details.
Click Invite A User.
On the Invite a user page, input the email address associated with your primary account
login and choose Admin.
Cursor clicking Admin radio button.
Click Send Invite.
Cursor clicking Send Invite.
```

We'll send an email to the address you provided asking you to join the account. As soon as you receive the email, you're ready to link your account logins.
Link Your Logins

To link your primary account login to your secondary account, follow these steps.

```
In your email client, open the account invitation.
Click Join This Account.
Cursor clicking Join This Account button.
On the Login screen, click Use your login to join this account.
Cursor clicking link to use existing login.
Input your primary account's username and password and click Log In & Join.
Cursor clicking button to log in.
```

Now your account logins are linked. The next time you log in to MailChimp, we'll ask you which account you want to access.

After you log in to either account, you'll be able to switch between them in the Profile menu. Click your profile name, choose Switch Account, and then click the name of the account you want to access.